# How to download multiple OECD files using loop in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to use a loop to download multiple files in OECD, but have not been successful.

1. Anyone know how to use the loop to download for many countries and many years (e.g. 2000-2019)?

2 How can save the file with the name: MEI_REAL_" country name"_ year.csv?

```
library(OECD)
data_names <- c("AUS", "BEL", "DEU")                    
data_names   

for(i in 1:length(data_names)) {  
  data_i <- get_dataset("MEI_REAL",
                              filter = list(NULL,data_names[i]),
                              start_time = 2017,
                              end_time = 2017)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(OECD)
data_names <- c("AUS", "BEL", "DEU")   

#empty vector to store the results of loop
df = vector()

for(i in data_names) {  
  saProduction <- get_dataset("MEI_REAL",
                                filter = list(NULL, i),
                                start_time = 2017,
                                end_time = 2017)
  df = rbind.data.frame(df, saProduction)
}

#individual dataframe 
df = split(df, df$LOCATION)
list2env(df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I run your suggest, but I only got the data set of DEU

Comment: I modified my answer, try again.

Comment: I tried and the data for all three countries is stored in df.  Thank you so much. I still have a question that is whether it is possible to save the data for each country and each year into different csv files?

Comment: Modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the code @*Nad Pat* suggested, added loops for years and it works. I tried to save the files but was not successful. Also, the time variable is time_quarter but I only want to split data by years, not quarters (e.g. AUS_2007).  Does anyone know how to save separate files for each country-year and how can I split the data by only year, not year_quater? I try to save manually (not using loops) and it works, but loops do not.

```
library(OECD)
data_names <- c("AUS", "BEL", "DEU")   
data_years <- c(2015:2017)

df = vector()

for(i in data_names) {  
  for (j in data_years) {
    saProduction <- get_dataset("MEI_REAL",
                                filter = list(NULL, i),
                                start_time = j,
                                end_time = j)
    df = rbind.data.frame(df, saProduction)
  }
}

head(df)

df = split(df, list(df$LOCATION, df$Time))
list2env(df,envir=.GlobalEnv)

for(i in data_names){
  for (j in data_years) {
    write.csv(i.j,file="i_j.csv") 
  }
}
```

Comment: You're using the same filename for every loop. That's why you're not saving more than one file. Would you consider using string interpolation?: `file=stringr::str_interp("${i}_${j}.csv")`

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for your suggestion. However, it only creates the file with the name as stated without data in the file.